# Fetch Google play user's library

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

I would like to fetch **all users's apps in library**. Google library includes all apps user have had, not only now **installed** or apps he have **logged into** throgh google acc.

Is there any way how to get them using google **APIs** or any sugestion to do it whatever way. *#notafraidofanything*

**What I can visually access:**

- Mine library when i go https://play.google.com/apps
- Other users apps he have logged into through google (in google play games)

*Thank you for your time.*